# URL Canonicalization (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, canonicalization

I would like to use my .htaccess file to add "www." to all URL's if there requested without it but my hopes are that I can do this without having to define the domain as I would like to use this code on many sites without having to edit it. Is this possible?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but is there a way to do this without having to specify the domain? I wish to use this code on many websites and hope to do so without having to edit the code even though its only a small change I know.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it would require pattern matching, which by itself is great and how .htaccess works mostly. But if you just pattern match a generic <domain.domainext> then how are you doing to stop someone from typing foo.com and getting www.foo.com but also typing foo2.com and then it spitting out www.foo2.com. You need some sort of control over the domain you want to add the www to correct? If you don't specify it the you are just creating a url rerouter.

Comment: If you truly want to make it generic, then change the condition to a regular extension to match your domains such as [A-z0-9]{3,}\.{1}[A-z]{3,4}

Comment: `[A-z]` includes all the punctuation between `Z` and `A` ([ \ ] ^ _ and backtick). You probably meant `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't answer your answer specifically.  My recommendation is to do this with your choice of server side of code.

In php you would do something like...

```
$host = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$url = explode(".", $host);
if (count($url) == 2){
    //no subdomain found
    redirect("www.".$host);
}
```

Update: This is going to have issues with domain names like example.co.uk, not sure if that is an issue.....I was trying to support subdomains on your site still (hence not just checking for www and appending).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML 5 Boilerplate uses this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will add "www." even if there is already a sub domain.